# RabbitMQ Executable Disappears Before Installation Begins on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, rabbitmq

I've been following the documentation on the official RabbitMQ site to install it on my Windows 7 computer. Installing Erlang and setting the environment variables has been trouble-free, but using the RabbitMQ installer has not worked out.

I have tried downloading the installer from both the GitHub and Bintray links as a regular user and administrator, but it does not seem to change the following problem: each time I double-click or right-click->Run as Administrator the installer it removes itself from the computer.

I've tried looking at processes in Task Manager, the Trash Bin, All Programs, and even in Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features, but there is no sign that the installer has done it's job.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software running? I'm getting my Win 7 VM set up at the moment to try and reproduce this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Using my administrative account, I installed Erlang 19.3 via the 64-bit installer [here](https://www.erlang.org/downloads/19.3) to `C:\erlang\19.3`. I then set the system-wide environment variable `ERLANG_HOME=C:\erlang\19.3`. I then used the same administrative account to install RabbitMQ 3.7.3. Everything went fine installing from an admin `cmd.exe` window or right-clicking and choosing "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Docker and Kitematic to run RabbitMQ image 3.6-management. The image works without any issues and appears to be a preferred option among my co-workers.